# Capistrano no such file to load -- deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

When I try to run any `cap` commands, I get a "no such file to load -- deploy" error.

Here is the output:

```
Tylers-MacBook-Pro:cap_app Tyler$ cap -T
/Users/Tyler/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': no such file to load -- deploy (LoadError)
from /Users/Tyler/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /Users/Tyler/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/capistrano-2.11.0/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:152:in `require'
from Capfile:1:in `load'
from /Users/Tyler/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/capistrano-2.11.0/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:93:in `instance_eval'
from /Users/Tyler/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/capistrano-2.11.0/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:93:in `load'
from /Users/Tyler/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/capistrano-2.11.0/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:172:in `load_from_file'
from /Users/Tyler/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/capistrano-2.11.0/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:89:in `load'
from /Users/Tyler/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/capistrano-2.11.0/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:86:in `block in load'
from /Users/Tyler/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/capistrano-2.11.0/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:86:in `each'
from /Users/Tyler/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/capistrano-2.11.0/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:86:in `load'
from /Users/Tyler/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/capistrano-2.11.0/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:65:in `block in load_recipes'
from /Users/Tyler/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/capistrano-2.11.0/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:65:in `each'
from /Users/Tyler/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/capistrano-2.11.0/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:65:in `load_recipes'
from /Users/Tyler/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/capistrano-2.11.0/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:31:in `execute!'
from /Users/Tyler/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/capistrano-2.11.0/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:14:in `execute'
from /Users/Tyler/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/capistrano-2.11.0/bin/cap:4:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/Tyler/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/cap:19:in `load'
from /Users/Tyler/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/cap:19:in `<main>'
```

Here is the Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.1'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'capistrano'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer'

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the web server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
#   gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'
```

config/deploy.rb

```
require 'bundler/capistrano'
set :application, "CapistranoApp" 
set :repository,  "ssh://ubuntu@weaponxo.com/~/projectdir.git"
set :applicationdir, "/var/www/#{application}"
set :domain, "ror.weaponxo.com"


set :scm, :git
set :branch, "master"
set :git_shallow_clone, 1
set :scm_verbose, true
# Or: `accurev`, `bzr`, `cvs`, `darcs`, `git`, `mercurial`, `perforce`, `subversion` or `none`

role :web, domain                          # Your HTTP server, Apache/etc
role :app, domain                          # This may be the same as your `Web` server
role :db,  domain, :primary => true # This is where Rails migrations will run

set :deploy_to, applicationdir
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache

# if you're still using the script/reaper helper you will need
# these http://github.com/rails/irs_process_scripts

# If you are using Passenger mod_rails uncomment this:
 namespace :deploy do
   task :start do ; end
   task :stop do ; end
   task :restart, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
     run "#{try_sudo} touch #{File.join(current_path,'tmp','restart.txt')}"
   end
  end
```

Capfile:

```
require 'deploy'
# Uncomment if you are using Rails' asset pipeline
# load 'deploy/assets'
Dir['vendor/gems/*/recipes/*.rb','vendor/plugins/*/recipes/*.rb'].each { |plugin| load(plugin) }
load 'config/deploy' # remove this line to skip loading any of the default tasks
```

I'm guessing the "deploy" is the reference to `require 'deploy'` from the Capfile.

What did I mess up?

Thanks

### Edit

Changing the first line of the Capfile to

```
load 'deploy' if respond_to?(:namespace) # cap2 differentiator
```

works.  Any idea why the Capfile ships by default with this "broken" line in it?  Do I need to do something different than `capify .`?

Comment: This happens on capistrano v3 as well. The default Capfile seem to be broken.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
load 'deploy'
```

(Assuming you're using capistrano 2).

Our capfile looks like this:

```
load 'deploy' if respond_to?(:namespace) # cap2 differentiator

# Uncomment if you are using Rails' asset pipeline
# load 'deploy/assets'

Dir['vendor/gems/*/recipes/*.rb','vendor/plugins/*/recipes/*.rb'].each { |plugin| load(plugin) }

load 'config/deploy' # remove this line to skip loading any of the default tasks
```

Comment: Thanks - Any idea why the default Capfile is broken?

Answer (score 8):

Downgrade your capistrano to the previous version 2.9.0.

The newest one (2.11.0) causes the problem you mentioned.

Comment: Capistrano 2.11.2 seems to be OK.

Comment: I downgraded from 3 to 2.15.5 b/c it wouldn't work at all with my current code. Not sure why that happens. You should specify the version in your gemfile so you know what you'll get. All I did was run bundle update for something else and it updated cap too. Kinda annoying.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my Capfile -- try it since you're on capistrano 2

```
load 'deploy' if respond_to?(:namespace) # cap2 differentiator

# Uncomment if you are using Rails' asset pipeline
# load 'deploy/assets'

Dir['vendor/gems/*/recipes/*.rb','vendor/plugins/*/recipes/*.rb'].each { |plugin| load(plugin) }

load 'config/deploy' # remove this line to skip loading any of the default tasks
```

Comment: Thanks - Any idea why the default Capfile is broken?

Answer (score 1):

I've just had this problem today.

The problem was caused by not specifying the cap gem version, and running bundle update, which updated cap to 3.* .

After following the advice here, I still had the same problem. However, after checking the output carefully, I noticed that the error was coming from cap 3.* not being able to load deploy.

This was strange, because I had then set the cap gem version to ~> 2, still had the error coming from cap 3.* . Did the same to downgrade the cap version to ~> 1, and again the error was still coming from cap 3.* .

It was fixed by removing cap 3.* from my gemset completely.

I was under the impression that I could have multiple gem versions installed, and as long as the version I wanted to use was specified in the Gemfile, then that would be the version used. I still have a couple of cap 2.* s installed although my Gemfile specifies ~> 1, the version 2 gems don't seem to impact, but having version 3.* installed too, causes me to have the problem described above by the OP.

Hope this might help someone else.

Paul

Comment: Wanna start a new question and post your gemfile? Someone who knows bundler better than me might have an idea.  Great fix though

Comment: I had multiple versions installed `capistrano (3.1.0, 2.15.5, 2.14.2)` but was not specifying the version in my Gemfile and it was creating the same error as in the question. Once I specified the  version in the Gemfile `gem 'capistrano', '~> 2.15.5'` I could do a `bundle exec cap deploy`.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem today, it was due to me having capistrano 3.* installed and this thread provided the solution that worked for me:

[Rails 4, Capistrano 3.0.0, cannot load such file -- deploy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19247818/rails-4-capistrano-3-0-0-cannot-load-such-file-deploy/21540945#21540945)

Answer (score -1):

So I ran into this same error. My mistake was is after installing the gem files I skipped the install steps and instead had used old 2.x version examples for my Capfile and deploy files...

So after doing bundle install try using the command `cap install STAGES=sandbox,qa,production`, or whichever stages you need.  After that it should overwrite your files. Go edit the files it added and you should be good to go.