# Unable to add load 'deploy/assets' to my capistrano deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, asset-pipeline

When i try de deploy my rails application with the command `cap deploy` it fails :

> ./config/deploy.rb:31:in `load': no such file to load -- deploy/assets
>   (LoadError)

This is due to the line
`load 'deploy/assets'`
in my capistrano deployment.rb file. This line is supposed to trigger asset precompilation during deployment.

According to bundle show I'm using :

- bundler (1.1.4)
- capistrano (2.12.0)
- rails (3.1.3)

why is it not working?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try moving the `load 'deploy/assets'` line from your `deploy.rb` file to your `Capfile`.

See this tutorial on [Capistrano with Rails](https://gist.github.com/2161449) for some more information. Although it seems that others put it in deploy.rb without any errors, so YMMV.

Also, you might want to check ou other SO questions like this one: [Capistrano no such file to load -- deploy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9370920/capistrano-no-such-file-to-load-deploy)