# Rails 4, Capistrano 3.0.0, cannot load such file -- deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, capistrano

I just ran bundle update and capistrano got updated to 3.0.0 but now when I run cap deploy I get an error and can't figure out how to fix this. I have been updating my server every day without problem until this update.

```
cap aborted!
cannot load such file -- deploy
/home/mark/rails_apps/myapp/Capfile:1:in `load'
/home/mark/rails_apps/myapp/Capfile:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

capfile

```
load 'deploy'
load 'deploy/assets'
load 'config/deploy' # remove this line to skip loading any of the default tasks
```

Comment: Capistrano v3 is completely incompatible with the previous version. But it's perfectly OK to keep using v2 until you're prepared to take the plunge.

Comment: How can can I find out what steps I need to upgrade or which version to downgrade to?

Comment: Capistrano official website: http://www.capistranorb.com/ Version history: http://rubygems.org/gems/capistrano/versions

Comment: I changed the gemfile to group :development do
  gem 'capistrano', '~> 2.15'
end but same error.

Comment: It seems not be able to load any files.

Comment: Capistrano 3 is broken!  Had to revert to version 2(15.4)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I had to run 
`gem uninstall capistrano`

then update the gemfile with 
`gem 'capistrano', '~> 2.15'`

and then run to reinstall the correct version again with 
`bundle update capistrano`

Comment: Thanks! I had multiple versions of capistrano. When I removed 1 version cap started working.

Answer (score 39):

I had to gem uninstall capistrano and selected version 3.0.0

(i.e. downgraded the gem to 2.x)

Comment: Thank you. But how come everything was broke until i uninstalled it?
I even didn't use that version, it was just in the bundler by accident.

Comment: You evidently ran bundle update? I have now fixed my version to 2.15.5. so it won't ever update again until I see a tutorial on the subject.

Comment: I had the same issue, downgrade it to capistrano 2.+ was the solution

Comment: Do you mean that Capistrano 3.0 doesn't support asset precompile? there must be a way to support that in Capistrano 3.0

Answer (score 18):

Make sure you are using bundle exec (most likely you have multiple gem versions of capistrano)

i.e.

`bundle exec cap -T`

Comment: Using `bundle exec cap production deploy:check` makes it pass as expected! TY!

Answer (score 8):

Instead of downgrading to Capistrano 2 use the new configuration from the current version.

```
require "capistrano/bundler"
require "capistrano/rails/assets"
require "capistrano/rails/migrations"
```

[See also this nice posting](https://semaphoreapp.com/blog/2013/11/26/capistrano-3-upgrade-guide.html), which summarises the differences between Capistrano 2 and 3.

Answer (score 4):

Add the related gems to your `Gemfile`

i.e. for

```
gem 'capistrano-bundler' # for capistrano/bundler
gem 'capistrano-rails' # for capistrano/rails/*
```

Do not downgrade to 2.x for this.

Comment: @sixty4bit please elaborate, or open a new stackoverflow question.

Comment: It's been a couple weeks but I think I had to add require: false to avoid the load error. Note that the upgrade guide indicates this: http://capistranorb.com/documentation/upgrading/

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem today and pastullo's solution above fixed it except that I had to run gem uninstall capistrano (as markhorrocks answered) not bundle uninstall capistrano.

I also found this blog on bundler very useful: http://viget.com/extend/bundler-best-practices

Thanks for sharing this as it saved me heaps of time. x

Answer (score 2):

The fastest way to fix this I have found is to backup the cap files (Capfile, config/deploy.rb, and config/deploy/*.rb) and then re capify (it's no longer called "capify"):

```
bundle exec cap install STAGES=staging,production
```

Then recreate your cap files from your backup. It will take you 5 minutes to do this and you'll be over the major Capistrano upgrade hump.

Answer (score 1):

I used

`bundle exec cap production deploy`

instead of just `cap production deploy`

Answer (score 0):

in my case I have changed my project ruby version. may be `bundle` also work here.

but I changed it to back what it was in previously.

ex:

```
rbenv local 2.4.1
```