# capistrano deployment error cap aborted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, capistrano

Here is my `deploy.rb`

```
set :application, "admin"
set :repository,  "here is my bitbucket repository"

set :scm, :git
# Or: `accurev`, `bzr`, `cvs`, `darcs`, `git`, `mercurial`, `perforce`, `subversion` or `none`
set :branch, "master"

set :rails_env, "production"

set :deploy_via, :copy

set :ssh_options, { forward_agent: true, port: 2020 }

set :keep_releases, 5

server "admin.mydomain.com", :app, :web, :db, primary: true

set :deploy_to "/var/www/vhosts/admin"
```

I have referred two links for configuring capistrano

[link 1](http://guides.beanstalkapp.com/deployments/deploy-with-capistrano.html) and [link 2](http://robmclarty.com/blog/how-to-deploy-a-rails-4-app-with-git-and-capistrano)

when i run `cap deploy:setup`

I am getting error as

```
cap aborted!
cannot load such file -- deploy
/home/seting/Documents/site/admin/Capfile:1:in `load'
/home/seting/Documents/site/admin/Capfile:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/seting/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/capistrano-3.0.0/lib/capistrano/application.rb:22:in `load_rakefile'
/home/seting/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/capistrano-3.0.0/lib/capistrano/application.rb:12:in `run'
/home/seting/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/capistrano-3.0.0/bin/cap:3:in `<top (required)>'
/home/seting/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/cap:23:in `load'
/home/seting/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/cap:23:in `<main>'
/home/seting/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/home/seting/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

**Edit 1**

This is my cap file

```
load 'deploy'
# Uncomment if you are using Rails' asset pipeline
     load 'deploy/assets'
Dir['vendor/gems/*/recipes/*.rb','vendor/plugins/*/recipes/*.rb'].each { |plugin| load(plugin) }
load 'config/deploy' # remove this line to skip loading any of the default tasks
```

Comment: Do you have your deploy.rb in the right path? (config/deploy.rb)

Comment: Yes correct only it is auto generated by using capify command

Comment: Can you post the contents of your `Capfile` please?

Comment: Are you using Cap V2 setup with Cap V3? They are incompatible.

Comment: @mtoast I have updated my cap file please check it.

Comment: @Electrawn In by console during exception it is showing as `capistrano-3.0.0` so i hope this is v3 right?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19247818/rails-4-capistrano-3-0-0-cannot-load-such-file-deploy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use RVM >= 1.11.3, you should add `rvm-capistrano` gem to your Gemfile and then `bundle install`.

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
cap deploy:setup
```

not

```
cap:deploy:setup
```

Comment: Sorry that is mistake in typing

Answer (score 0):

On line 1 of your capfile, instead of

```
load 'deploy'
```

use

```
load 'deploy' if respond_to?(:namespace)
```