# Capistrano & Symfony: cap aborted! LoadError: cannot load such file -- capifony_symfony2

Tags: symfony, capistrano, capistrano3

I get the following errors when running a deployment:

```
cap aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- capifony_symfony2
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
C:/xampp/htdocs/surveys6/Capfile:3:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load'
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load_rakefile'
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:689:in `raw_load_rakefile'
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in load_rakefile'
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:93:in `load_rakefile'
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:77:in `block in run'
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/capistrano-3.11.0/lib/capistrano/application.rb:14:in `run'
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/capistrano-3.11.0/bin/cap:3:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby22/bin/cap:23:in `load'
C:/Ruby22/bin/cap:23:in `<main>'
```

I'm using:
Capistrano Version: 3.11.0 (Rake Version: 10.4.2)
Symfony version 2.7.49

Can anyone advise, I feel like it may be connected to the top answer here?.. [Rails 4, Capistrano 3.0.0, cannot load such file -- deploy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19247818/rails-4-capistrano-3-0-0-cannot-load-such-file-deploy)

Comment: Unsure but I've had issues with Symfony and Cap as well and ended up using Deployer instead - https://deployer.org/

Comment: Although, I have not used capistrano/symphony with windows, I'll try my best to help. Can you post the contents of `Capfile`?

Answer (score 1):

Probably was a case of aligning the legacy software. I got the uninstall of Capistrano 3.11 and install of Capistrano 2.15.9 to work eventually. And this version of Capistrano works with my oldish version of Symfony.