# Capistrano - "cannot load such file --deploy"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano, cap

Working on an existing rails project that is set up to deploy with Capistrano. Trying to determine my first step in figuring out this error. Can anyone point me in the right direction of what I need to do?

```
cap aborted!
cannot load such file -- deploy
/Users/lrh/Projects/Rails/febennett.com/Capfile:1:in `load'
/Users/lrh/Projects/Rails/febennett.com/Capfile:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/lrh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@febennett/gems/capistrano-      
3.0.1/lib/capistrano/application.rb:22:in `load_rakefile'
/Users/lrh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@febennett/gems/capistrano-
3.0.1/lib/capistrano/application.rb:12:in `run'
/Users/lrh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@febennett/gems/capistrano-3.0.1/bin/cap:3:in `<top   
(required)>'
/Users/lrh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@febennett/bin/cap:23:in `load'
/Users/lrh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@febennett/bin/cap:23:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Capfile Below

```
load 'deploy'
# Uncomment if you are using Rails' asset pipeline
load 'deploy/assets'
load 'config/deploy' # remove this line to skip loading any of the default tasks
```

Thanks! Hope this is sufficient information.

Comment: Show us `Capfile`.  Show us `config/deploy.rb` (mask out anything sensitive). Show us how you are invoking capistrano.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Capistrano no such file to load -- deploy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9370920/capistrano-no-such-file-to-load-deploy)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You're using Capistrano 3, but the project you're using was probably set up for Capistrano 2. Version 3 was a complete rewrite and requires a fair amount of configuration updates to work.

Assuming you have the correct 2.x version of Capistrano in your project's `Gemfile`, you should be using `bundle exec cap` (to use your project's version) instead of just `cap` (which will use the globally-installed 3.x version).

There is an [upgrade guide](http://www.capistranorb.com/documentation/upgrading/) available, though it's not terribly in depth.

Comment: Thanks - this was indeed the case.

Comment: Thank you for this. I thought about this was the case. I'm assuming capistrano 3.0 is aliased over 2.0+

Answer (score 1):

You need to move/delete your older cap files as exactly your project was before using cap 2 instead of cap 3. Now if you want to upgrade your cap to 3 do following before this.

Delete the following mentioned files or you can simply move same files somewhere else as below:

```
mkdir old_cap
mv Capfile old_cap
mv config/deploy.rb old_cap
mv config/deploy/ old_cap # --> only for multistage setups
```

Now you can proceed with same command. All the best :)